# Is there a editor for MIPS Assembly .s files?

Tags: text-editor, assembly

At the moment I use different text editors, but none of them highlight any code or help in any other way to simplify the code writing. Are there any good text editors out there for MIPS?

Answer (score 1):

**[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/)** editor (open source, cross platform) supports this. You need to install lexer "Assembly MIPS" from Addon Manager.

- call menu item "Plugins/ Addon Manager/ Install"
- enter there MIPS to find the needed lexer
- confirm to install it

Lexer handles .s and .asm extensions, but you can change this in the Lexer Properties dialog. Example screenshot:

[image: **MIPS lexer in CudaText**]